# Capture video frames of DRM protected video in chrome

Tags: drm, mpeg-dash, widevine

I'm building a video player for my application, which will play DRM protected videos (WideVine on Chrome and Firefox) using dash.js and video.js. As part of this application i want to be able to annotate the video and send the data back to server.

Annotation data should be attached to a frame of the video instead of timestamps and the application should send the frame and related annotation data to server. Is it possible to capture the raw frames of the Widevine DRM protected video in chrome or firefox and send them to server using webGL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to capture the decrypted frame of a DRM protected video. This would to some degree defeat the DRM system. It's only possible for non-DRM protected streams.

Comment: Figured that this is not possible after reading some more on the internet